# Angular 4 multiple dropdown selected

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

What I want to do is selected of multiple select.

**Below is my HTML**

```
<div class="form-group"  *ngIf="edituserForm">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">User</label>
   <select multiple  class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="user_id" #user_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="this.edituser_id" required>
       <option *ngFor="let user of users;" [value]="user.user_id" [selected]="this.edituser_id == user.user_id">{{user.employee_no}}</option>
   </select>
</div>

{{this.edituser_id}}

<button type="button" (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
```

**My Component**

```
edituser_id: any = [];
edituserForm: boolean = false;

edit(){
 this.edituserForm = true;
 this.edituser_id = ["1","2"];
}
```

**Below is the screen which always selected the 1st user without the 2nd user**

[image]

**And below is what I want in my screen**
[image]

I already try a lot of ways, but still cannot make it. Hope you guys can help and really appreciate it.

Comment: You should not use 'this' keyword in your template. [selected]="this.edituser_id == user.user_id" should be [selected]="edituser_id == user.user_id". Also edituser_id is an array. You need to check if user.user_id exists in that array

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Tried your code and it worked fine, but I had to guess some parts, as you haven't provided the minimal code to reproduce the issue. So please do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your template:

```
<div class="form-group"  *ngIf="edituserForm">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">User</label>
    <select multiple  class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="user_id" #user_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="edituser_id" required>
        <option *ngFor="let user of users;" [value]="user.user_id" [selected]="edituser_id.includes(user.user_id)">{{user.employee_no}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answered, but unfortunately still selected the 1st user only